# ¿Cómo obtener la id del item al hacer onClick? (ListView)

Tags: java, android

El problema es que sino abro previamente el *menú contextual* se cierra al hacer `onClick` marcándome **null**, ya que al abrir el *menú contextual* obtengo la **id**, pues mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo obtener la **id** del *item* al hacer `onClick` encima del *item* y así no necesitar abrir el *menú contextual*?

Este es mi código:

`MainActivity`

```
        // Se recuperan todas las personas de la base de datos
        recuperarTodasPersonas();

        // Asocio los menús contextuales a listViewPersonas.
        registerForContextMenu(listViewPersonas);

        // onClick item ListView

        listViewPersonas.setClickable(true);
        listViewPersonas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                muestraDialogo((int)info.id);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que se sobreescribe. En este metodo creo el menu contextual
     * para el ListView de personas.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        info =  (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.opciones_personas, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_contextual_editar_persona:
                editarPersona((int)info.id);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_contextual_eliminar_persona:
                eliminarPersona((int)info.id);
                recuperarTodasPersonas();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
        }
    }


// método que inicio al hacer OnClick

    public void muestraDialogo(int p_id) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        DialogFragment newFragment = BlurDialogInformacion.newInstance(p_id, this);
        newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
    }
```

Comment: Me puedes ayudar? @Jorgesys :)

Answer (score 1):

Tu fallo es `NullPointerException`. Se debe a que el elemento al que intentas acceder tiene como valor `null`, o lo que en tu caso es lo mismo, no se ha inicializado.

En tu método `masInformacion((int) info.id)` estás intentando acceder al objeto `info` que al parecer no está inicializado.

Tu objeto `info` solo se inicializa cuando el menú se abre, en el método `onCreateContextMenu`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero al realizar lo que me comentas recibo el siguiente error: `Error:(198, 61) error: cannot find symbol variable menuInfo` @cnbandicoot

Comment: Eso es porque la variable `menuInfo` no es accesible desde tu `onCreate`. ¿Cual es tu intención con el método `masInformacion`? ¿Se tiene que abrir el menú al dar click sobre el `ListView`? Infórmame para poder ayudarte

Comment: El método ''masInformacion` lo utilizo para cargar datos de una `ListView ` que relleno desde mi `Sqlite` . Lo del menú me refiero que si primero pulso sobre un item y abro el menú contextual luego al hacer clic en el item si funciona, pero si abro la aplicación y hago clic sin antes haber abierto el menú contextual me marca ese error @cnbandicoot

Comment: Pues lo que está claro es que no puedes utilizar el `id` de info, porque aún no se ha instanciado. Tienes que coger ese `id` que utilizas en ese método de otra manera. Si no pones el método, no puedo ayudarte de otra forma.

Comment: He añadido la `clase` con el método para ver si así puedes ayudarme mejor, los métodos que faltan es porque opino que no son necesario y así la clase está más limpia para que puedas ayudarme, gracias @cnbandicoot !